# How can i set value in a datagridview linkbutton column in Winform appl. using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I am new in Winform application, now i am binding a datagridview, How can i
set value in a datagridview linkbutton column when i set 'Edit', 'Delete' columns are as linkbutton" just like my attached image with this question

please explain the code for edit or delete[image] feature

Comment: ***new in Winform*** - well if possible you should jump right to WPF as soon as possible. I wasted much time playing around with winforms. It's really a hacky world. If you accept to use custom controls already written by others, it's OK but if you want to try it yourself (customize, improve its appearance, behavior, ...) then you will waste much time and finally end up learning the newest UI technology WPF sooner or later.

Comment: For basics better refer to some tutorial, this question is not very clear and quite broad.http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

You can set `Text` property of your `DataGridViewLinkColumn` and also set its `UseColumnTextForLinkValue` to `true`, this way the text will display on each cells of that column.

---

Use `CellFormatting` if you want to show different text in each cell of your link column.

You can use [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView` and Set the value of those cells:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    //If this is header row or new row, do nothing
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex == this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
        return;

    // If this is 4th column, Set the value to Edit
    //if (e.ColumnIndex=this.dataGridView1.Columns["YourEditColumnName"].Index)
    if(e.ColumnIndex==4)
    {
        e.Value = "Edit";
    }

    // If this is 5th column, Set the value to Delete
    //if(e.ColumnIndex=this.dataGridView1.Columns["YourDeleteColumnName"].Index)
    if(e.ColumnIndex==5)
    {
        e.Value = "Delete";
    }
}
```

Remember to assign `dataGridView1_CellFormatting` to your datagridview `CellFormatting` event.

Comment: Sir, by using the above code i have created the Edit and Delete columns with appropriate value, i can check it using break point in c#,  but it is not displaying in the data gridview. Is Anything more to do after the above code to append that  column in the gridview..??

Comment: @SalamIndianoor Did you  assign dataGridView1_CellFormatting to your datagridview CellFormatting event? If you set a breakpoint on event, does it fire?

Comment: Yes i have set   private void grdEmployees_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)...is it you mean..?

Comment: @SalamIndianoor Did you used correct index for your edit and delete column? in `if(e.ColumnIndex==4)`, instead of 4 you should put index of your edit column, and in `if(e.ColumnIndex==5)` instead of 5 you should put index of your delete column.

Comment: @SalamIndianoor you should go to designer, select your datagridview, in property windows in events tab, select CellFormating event, open the dropdown and select  grdEmployees_CellFormatting

Comment: @SalamIndianoor maybe you are deleting column when passing data to datagridview?

Comment: yes..cell formating were done..but in my gridEditcolum these colums are 7,8 index,but when it displaying values at run time, columns are  viewing at 4,5 index..anything wrong with this..??

Comment: Its better to access columns by its names, go to `Columns` property of dataGridView and see what's name of those 2 columns and then check edit of answer.

Comment: @SalamIndianoor Now you can use `if (e.ColumnIndex=this.dataGridView1.Columns["YourEditColumnName"].Index)` for your edit column and `if(e.ColumnIndex=this.dataGridView1.Columns["YourDeleteColumnName"].Index)` for your delete column. remeber you shoud use column name here not text, Name proprty of column.

Comment: Woow..Its all right now..the above code is working...thanks for spending your valuable time sir..